# datepicker addClass to a specific datepicker only

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have more then one datepickers in the page and the option:

```
beforeShow : function(input, inst) {
                     $(inst.dpDiv).addClass("MY_CLASS_EXAMPLE");
}
```

adds the class to all the datepicker instances.

Is there any way to add a class only to this specific instance?

Thanks

Comment: do you have any id or something that identifies it? if not the only option that came to my mind is get all the datepickers, and get only the one that you are looking for with [x]

Answer (score 0):

```
beforeShow : function(input, inst) {
    if($("input").attr("id")=="Your_Specif_Input_Id")
    {
        $("input").addClass("Your_Class_Name") ;
    }
}
```